# Python Multiprocessing not working with Python 3.10.9 on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-3.11

I am currently trying to create a proxy class that instantiates a new process and forwards all method calls to that subprocess. The code for this is not completely finished, but the code below should work (except for that it is not asynchronous yet).

What I observe is that the code below does not work for Python 3.10.9 in Windows 10, but it does work for Python 3.8.10 on WSL.

Does anyone have an idea what may cause this issue?

```
import multiprocessing

def setup_subprocess(
    object_type,
    args: tuple,
    kwargs: dict,
    queue_in: multiprocessing.Queue,
    queue_out: multiprocessing.Queue,
):
    instance = object_type(*args, **kwargs)
    while True:
        method_name, method_args, method_kwargs = queue_in.get()
        result = getattr(instance, method_name)(
            *method_args,
            **method_kwargs
        )
        queue_out.put(result)


class DedicatedProcessObject():
    def __init__(self, object_type, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queue_in = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.queue_out = multiprocessing.Queue()

        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=setup_subprocess,
            args=(
                object_type,
                args,
                kwargs,
                self.queue_in,
                self.queue_out
            ),
        )

        self.process.start()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def method(*args, **kwargs):
            self.queue_in.put((name, args, kwargs))
            result = self.queue_out.get()
            return result
        return method

class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b='b'):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
    def test(self, c, d='d'):
        return self.a,self.b,c,d

x = TestClass('a')
y = DedicatedProcessObject(TestClass, 'a')

print(x.test('c'))
print(y.test('c'))
```

The expected output is as follows but only the first line shows up on Windows:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Upon further inspection, I noticed that `process.is_alive()` returned `False` and that `process.exitcode` was set to `1`. I'm not sure how to derive any further debugging information.

Comment: Are you missing a `if __name__ == '__main__':` some place, say 6 lines from the end

Comment: Some IDE's don't properly capture stderr from child processes making it more difficult to debug. Running from CMD should give the error text. I also however suspect as JonSG does that you are simply missing the needed import gaurd: `if __name__ == "__main__":` which is required any time you use spawned processes rather than forked processes (google spawn vs fork in python)

Comment: How does the import guard work when executing code in a Jupyter notebook?